# Firestore Queries with more than 2 where clauses return no documents

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a query with 3 where clauses

There is no error returning in the `console.log`

If I comment `.where('eventFromDateTime', '>=', currentDate)` then only it returns document.

Could you tell me what is wrong with this query please?

Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have any error handling on it.  Please do so, and see what the error message says.  Also, we can't see the data you have in your database, so we have no way of know if this query should return anything at all.  If you are clearly getting 0 results in your snapshot handler, you should edit the question to show examples of actual documents that should be returned.  Note also that we can't see what `user.propertyId` is either - hard code everything so there are no unknowns here.

Comment: Thanks Doug for your quick response. I have added more details. Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: We still can't see actual data in your database, so we don't know what this query is actually going to do with that data.  As I suggested before, you should show examples of documents that should match your query but are not in the query results.

Comment: I have uploaded data screenshot. eventFromDatetime and eventToDateTime are timestamp values

Answer (score 1):

the format of `const currentDate = new Date();` is not the same as the string you have saved in `eventFromDateTime`. This means that the where condition will not work properly.

`currentDate` is an object and `eventFromDateTime` is a string

Comment: eventFromDatetime and eventToDateTime are timestamp values

Comment: a timestamp in firebase is not the same as `new Date()` - it needs to be converted `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());`

Comment: I tried    const currentDate = firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()); and still having same problem

Comment: This isn't accurate - you are allowed to pass Date objects in a query.  They will get converted to Timestamp type objects automatically for the purpose of querying timestamp type fields.  The field in question here is in fact a timestamp field, not a formatted string.